# Using AMD graphics card with Ubuntu (Sound)

Tags: sound, ati, hdmi

I understand this has been asked few times and I've read through few threads as swell but I didn't understand everything:
I've read [AMD graphics drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474956/amd-graphics-drivers) and [fglrx: No matching Device section for instance... found. how to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227721/fglrx-no-matching-device-section-for-instance-found-how-to-fix-it). Both are helpful.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (Gnome/KDE) -- not using Unity.

1. When I use proprietary drivers

a. in KDE the desktop looks like its zoomed in but when any app is opened it looks good

b. in GNOME everything looks like zoomed in

2. For open source drivers everything looks good.

I've a TV with speaker connected to HDMI and audio system connected to SPDIF port.
I can't seem to get audio out from HDMI

a. When I switch output in KDE then I can run test and hear sound from TV.

b. In GNOME I don't even see option of master audio as HDMI.

Can someone explain these things?

Comment: What AMD card do you have? What monitor do you have? Have you looked at the DPI settings in your desktop environment? What does pavucontrol say about your audio devices?

Comment: I'm using HD7850, Sony TV is being used as monitor, Actually got scaling issue resolved when I updated to 15.04 from 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

The sound device on your HDMI should appear the same whether you use Proprietary (fglrx) or Open Source (Mesa) drivers.

On AMD cards it is run through the ALSA drivers, and is on a separate PCI sub-device as far as software is concerned.

You probably simply do not have it set as your default sound output.   You should be able to do this in the appropriate audio settings for your desktop environment(s).

Comment: GNOME doesn't show audio through HDMI as an option in sound settings. KDE shows the correct HDMI and even if I make HDMI default sound is not routed through it.